# Enemy sprite moving to a specific way depending on how it spawns

Tags: c#, monogame

So I have a code where the sprite spawn outside the window and I want it to move on a specific straight line depending on where it spawn say if the sprite spawn at the top it goes at the bottom and vise versa if the sprite then spawn to the left it will go right and vise versa.
Game1.cs code:

```
 public class Game1 : Game
 {
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    Player player;
    List<Enemy> enemies = new List<Enemy>();


    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }


    protected override void Initialize()
    {


        base.Initialize();
    }


    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        //player
        Texture2D playertexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Player");
        player = new Player(new Vector2(350, 175), playertexture);

        //enemy
        Texture2D enemytexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Enemy");
        Random random = new Random();
        var width = GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width;
        var height = GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height;


        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {

            enemies.Add(new Enemy(new Vector2(random.Next(width, width + 100), random.Next(0, height)), enemytexture));
            enemies.Add(new Enemy(new Vector2(random.Next(0 - 100, 0), random.Next(0, height)), enemytexture));
            enemies.Add(new Enemy(new Vector2(random.Next(0, width), random.Next(-100, 0)), enemytexture));
            enemies.Add(new Enemy(new Vector2(random.Next(0, width), random.Next(height, height + 100)), enemytexture));
        }




    }

    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {

    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
            Exit();
        foreach (Enemy enemy in enemies)
        {
            enemy.Update(gameTime);
        }
        player.Update(gameTime);



        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        spriteBatch.Begin();
        foreach (Enemy enemy in enemies)
        {
            enemy.Draw(spriteBatch);
        }
        player.Draw(spriteBatch);

        spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

Enemy.cs

```
class Enemy
{
    Texture2D enemytexture;
    Vector2 enemyposition;


    public Enemy(Vector2 enemyposition, Texture2D enemytexture)
    {
        this.enemyposition = enemyposition;
        this.enemytexture = enemytexture;


    }

    public void Update(GameTime gametime)
    {
        enemyposition.X++;
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(enemytexture, enemyposition, Color.White);
    }
}
```

I wonder if I can do this in a way?

```cs
enemies.Add(new Enemy(new Vector2(random.Next(width, width + 100), random.Next(0, height)), enemytexture, enemyposition.X++));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're on the right track with your thinking but the code you posted isn't quite right.

It looks like what you're really trying to do is give the enemy a *direction* when it spawns. So let's start at the `Enemy` class and see how that might look:

```cs
class Enemy
{
    Texture2D enemytexture;
    Vector2 enemyposition;
    Vector2 enemydirection;

    public Enemy(Vector2 enemyposition, Texture2D enemytexture, Vector2 enemydirection)
    {
        this.enemyposition = enemyposition;
        this.enemytexture = enemytexture;
        this.enemydirection = enemydirection;
    }

    public void Update(GameTime gametime)
    {
        enemyposition += enemydirection;
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(enemytexture, enemyposition, Color.White);
    }
}
```

Now, when you spawn an enemy you just need to pass in another `Vector2` that defines the direction like so:

```cs
enemies.Add(new Enemy(new Vector2(random.Next(width, width + 100), random.Next(0, height)), enemytexture, new Vector2(-1, 0));
```

Comment: Thanks I never felt so dumb thinking that I can do new Vector2(-1, 0)) thanks so much

Comment: Don't worry about it bro  you get an answer. I get stack points and we both make the world I slightly better place. It's a win, win, win.